# Grab the positioning of a layer inside a precomposed layer?

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I have a precomposed layer that contains many shapes. Inside my global comp, I have various positions being applied to the precomposed layer. Unfortunately, I need everything in my precomposed layer to go to the global comp due to lottie requirements. I am now looking for a way to grab each position of each layer inside this precomposed layer. How can I do that?

I have tried with this expression:
comp("precomposedcomp").layer("precomposedcomplayer").transform.position

This expression works, but not the way I intended. It grabs the position of the layer inside the precomposed layer. The issue is that the positioning is set in the global comp... How could I possibly get this position? Assuming comps are exact same size.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to Layer Space Transforms:

[Parenting a null causes unexpected results](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17615/parenting-a-null-causes-unexpected-results/17619#17619)

https://thatsmadden.wordpress.com/2014/12/31/tocomp-and-toworld/

https://ae-expressions.docsforadobe.dev/layer-space.html

I think you could use "toWorld" to determine where the layer is in your outer comp.